# CATIA VBA Setting NCMfgOutput

Tags: vba, catia

How can i change settings of Machining ?

I can access to some settings but not to 'NCMfgOutput'.

Any ideas?

Sample what i'm able to do in VBA :

```
`Sub CATMain()
 
Dim mySetting As SettingController
Set mySetting = CATIA.SettingControllers.Item("CATVizVisualizationSettingCtrl")

Dim myValue As String
myValue = mySetting.LineicCgrMode

mySetting.LineicCgrMode = False

mySetting.SaveRepository
mySetting.Commit


End Sub`
```

C# :

`VisualizationSettingAtt setting = (VisualizationSettingAtt)CATIA.SettingControllers.Item("CATVizVisualizationSettingCtrl"); return !setting.AllZBufferElementMode;`

**But when i'm trying to access to 'NCMfgOutput' setting i got some issues :**

VBA :

```
`Sub CATMain()

Dim mySetting As SettingController
Set mySetting = CATIA.SettingControllers.Item("NCMfgOutput")

mySetting.PostPro = "IMS"

mySetting.SaveRepository
mySetting.Commit


End Sub`
```

C# :

I don't find the right reference, i searched in PROCESSITF.LibTabSettingAtt, PROCESSITF.TreeTabSettingAtt, PROCESSITF.VerifTabSettingAtt.

According to Automation documentation :

NCMfgOutput :
PostPro
Role: Choose the Post Processor company
Detailed role: Choose the Post Processor company

Type: string
Default value:
Default Value Role: By default no company preference is done
Values: CENIT CENIT company selection
IMS IMS company selection
ICAM ICAM company selection

---

Any ideas? :)